The sum $f(x)= \sum_{p \le x} e^{\frac{1}{p\log p}}$ is very close to $\pi(x)$. Why is that?
The prime counting function $\pi(x)$ counts the number of primes less than a given $x$. There are other counting functions like Chebyshev's functions which count sums of logarithms of primes up to a given magnitude as well.
I am wondering why this summatory function (which is similar to Chebyshev's functions) over primes $p$ $$f(x)= \sum_{p \le x} e^{\frac{1}{p\log p}} $$ so closely approximates $\pi(x)$. For example, I wrote some python code that tells me $f(x)-\pi(x)<2$ for $x<10^7$.

Are there heuristics to support that $f(x)$ closely approximates $\pi(x)$?

I suspect $f(x)-\pi(x)$ grows slowly like $\log \log x$ or maybe even is bounded above by a constant. Thanks.

For large $p$ , the expression in the sum is very close to $1$. If you sum up just $1$ , you get exactly $\pi(x)$

Since $e^{1/p\log p}=1+O(1/p\log p)$ and the sum
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_p{1\over p\log p}
&=\sum_{k\ge1}\sum_{2^k\le p<2^{k+1}}{1\over p\log p} \\
&\le\sum_{k\ge1}{1\over k2^k}\sum_{p\le 2^{k+1}}1=\sum_{k\ge1}{\pi(2^{k+1})\over k2^k} \\
&\le \text{const}\cdot\sum_{k\ge1}{2^{k+1}\over k2^k\log(2^{k+1})} \\
&\le \text{const}\cdot\sum_{k\ge1}{1\over k(k+1)}<\infty,
\end{aligned}
$$
we conclude that
$$
\sum_{p\le x}e^{1/p\log p}=\sum_{p\le x}1+O\left(\sum_{p\le x}{1\over p\log p}\right)=\pi(x)+O(1).
$$
